# Magento 2 category custom attribute call base url

Tags: magento2, category

In **`Magento 2`** I created Custom attribute as a **`Textarea`** then i call that content in particular Category.

So Now My Problem is I want to call base url in that dynamically so that i added like this

**`<a title="Test" href="{{store url="test.html "}}"> Test</a>`** but it's not working how to call store url in **`category custom attribute`**

it comes like this `http://domain.com/admin/cms/wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3tzdG9yZSB1cmw9ImZydWl0cy12ZWdldGFibGVzLXBsYW50cy9mcnVpdHMuaHRtbCAifX0,/key/36565656sdgfjsdfsdgfhsdyhfuhsdfsghfgsdhfbsd9a185e68/`

Comment: which url called yet?

Comment: check my updated question i added frontend url

Comment: let me know which code you have used for frontend to show your content

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
echo $catbgimg = $category->getData('myattribute');

Comment: try $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry(‌​'current_category');‌​//get current category 
$catbgimg = $category->getData('myattribute');
$filterManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider')->getPageFilter()->filter($catbgimg); and let me know

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING)

Comment: have you try echo $filterManager?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'